# How to use pivot and have 2 different aggregate functions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table with 1 date column. I want to group the dates by year and month so that I have a matrix such as:

```
Year Jan Feb Mar...Dec Total
2015.....
2016  10  15  10... 10   115
2017.....
```

Is this possible to achieve using the `PIVOT` function, and how exactly do I use it to achieve the above?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve without PIVOT

```
SELECT
   DATEPART(yyyy,t.the_date) as year,
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(mm,t.the_date)=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Jan,
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(mm,t.the_date)=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Feb,
...
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(mm,t.the_date)=12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Dec,
   COUNT(*) as Total
FROM the_table t
GROUP BY DATEPART(yyyy,t.the_date)
```

Comment: This works too. Would it still be possible to use `PIVOT` for such a query and would it perform better than `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

try using this query : -

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            year(yourDate) as [year],left(datename(month,yourDate),3)as [month], 
            Amount 
        FROM YourTableName
    ) as s
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(Amount)
        FOR [month] IN (jan, feb, mar, apr, 
        may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec)
    )AS pvt
```